# better performance on database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on an web app that has a grading system. For this I have a fixed 10 different types of exam.

**exam_1, exam_2, ... exam_10**

that is per student. The case is the student will take a random exam, it maybe exam_10 at first and exam_3 and second.

I want to store the scores into database which is the key is student_id so what I'm thinking of the design is:

1. student_id, exam_type, exam_score
2. student_id, exam_1, exam_2, ... exam_10
3. or you have a better option in mind please share it to me.

**I want to know which approach is better in performance for you guys that has more experience than a newbie like me.**

**Update:**
Example Queries that i will run

1. Which student has score in this exam
2. What is the over all score of the student in all exam ( I'm going to get all exam of a student score then compute the average in the core )
3. Display all score relative to their exam type per student

Comment: The only decent approach is `1`. Now if we only think about performance the best approach will depend on the queries you're going to run

Comment: @MostyMostacho I updated some queries that I will be using.

Comment: Stop worrying about "performance". First *fix/design* the database model so that is *normalized*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to focus on performance to evaluate design here? A single instance of MySQL can probably run more than 10k select queries a second on a commodity hw with right indexes whichever design you choose. I think you should consider other non-functional attributes like maintainability, extensibility, expressiveness.

So, I would go with number 1. student_id, exam_type, exam_score. This makes it easier to add another type of exam later on. Also if you want to do aggregation (min, max, avg), select queries will be much easier.

Comment: or even having an examSequence so the person is not locked into the 10 originally noted.

Comment: Well, I assumed that the dataset will be small enough to fit into memory. I haven't really ran any tests on MySQL but I've seen much more than 10k happening on postgresql on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have huge numbers of students, using option 1 is good enough for these simple aggregation in terms of performance.

With huge numbers of students, you may need to consider data warehouse option to aggregate your data in a cube first.